# What job title do I put on my CV for part time student work?

Tags: resume, title, job-description

I am about to write my CV and I currently have a job as a software developer but in a student position.

What is my job title? Would it be too much to call myself software developer when I am only working 15 hours a week even if I am doing the same job as the other (full-time) software developers.

Should I be called a student assistant/worker/employee? Based on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student_assistant) Wiki page, it seems a student assistant must be employed at an educational institution.

What would be appropriate?

Comment: Are you being _paid_ as a software developer?  Or is this an industry placement?

Comment: I am not being paid as a software developer since I do not hold a degree but it's neither an industry placement. It's just a part-time job I am doing while I am studying. I am doing software development; however, my boss could ask me to do any ad hoc tasks.

Comment: "Would it be too much to call myself software developer when I am only working 15 hours a week..." - The hours you work per week is not important. Just use the same title/description you were hired for. For example, if the listing said "Student Assistant" then that's what you should write for the title. If you're not sure now what your title is, you should ask your boss and write that in your CV. If you want to mention separately or in bullet points that you developed software as part of your duties, do that.

Answer (score 1):

## What would you like to make it?

Ultimately this falls to you. Whatever position you list is selling you to a potential employer. There are a few things to keep in mind:

- **It needs to reflect what you were doing.** If you had software developer responsibilities you need to reflect that in the title or summary. You
  can expand further in your job description and summary if you would prefer to put a more diluted title (see below as to why).
- **You need to be able to back it up!** If you're successful in an interview and a potential employer calls your past workplace to
  verify your employment are they going to deny what you've listed? Be
  sure to list something that's going to appropriately be backed up by
  your past employer to your new one.
- **Don't hide that it was a student engagement.** Dawny's suggestion to list this as an internship is a good one. I also like the idea of
  listing it as:

  > Software Developer (Student Placement)

Provided you reflect your position accurately and you can back it up with future employers then you can list this however you feel best represents you.

Comment: Thank you. I will take your advice. I am just unsure if it's called an internship or student placement. I have been working there for almost 4 years and it's completely independent from my studies. In my country, it's quite common that companies hire students since they demand a lower salary because they want to gain some knowledge and practice in the sector they want to work in.

Comment: Internships are usually full time, for 3 - 6 months in duration. Student placement would be a better description, since it reflects that you are going to school full time and working part-time. A similar term would be "co-op" but that's usually when working is a requirement for getting your degree. (Co-ops are common in engineering programs.)

Comment: Or, if it is truly independent from your studies, list it as "part-time". For example "Software developer (part-time)"

Answer (score -2):

Your title is "Intern/Sofware Developer."  This title provides the context that you were a junior member of staff, that you had some coding responsibility, that you were not just a piece of fluff, but that you actually contributed to the product.  It is not misleading, it is fully descriptive. Were I to interview you tomorrow, I would read the words "intern/software developer" and know EXACTLY what to expect.